# Azure Devops - Missing changsets locally

Tags: permissions, tfvc, changeset

I have a "Root" project that has both a TFVC "repo" and some GIT repos.  Using VS2019 and a folder in the TFVC path, I added a new sub folder and added some files in to the new folder.  I checked them in.  Made some file changes and checked them in.  In VS2109, checking the history at the root shows changesets for everything not related to my new folder.  A find on the changeset 17 shows nothing.

If I go to the portal, I can see the changesets there in the Contents tab.  They have my name on them.  However, I do not have permission to see the changeset details.  There is no history in the History tab.  I created the organization and I'm the admin.

I can get the history and changeset details in another folder in the same parent folder.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the issue - PEBKAC.  I created a vendor group with access only to the folder for the project the vendor is working on.  In TFS this can be a pain because they need read access to traverse the folder path to their folder.  I granted the group access at the root.  Then I denied read access on every sub-folder below the root except for the one the vendor requires.  It appears that I, as the administrator of the group, got added to the group automatically...and the deny took precedence.  After I removed myself from the group I had access again.

Deny is always something to be avoided if at all possible because it takes precedence.  I don't know how to avoid it.  Just glad I did deny myself access to fix it - hope that's not possible as the org owner.

The oddity of having access to some folders and not others was because I had not completed setting the deny read in those folders.